# Trying to send a message from javascript program on Intel Galileo to a node-red server running on my Labtop

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, node-red

Below is my javascript program.

```
var nobel = require('nobel)'
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: '111.111.111.111',
  path: '/myTest'
  port: 1880,
  method: 'POST'
}

callback = function (response) {
  var str = '';
  response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });
}

var req = http.request(options,callback);
req.write('helloWorld');
req.end();
```

Below is the http input node on my flow on nodeRed, which is running on my laptop.

[image: Node-RED http node]

The ip address of my laptop is 111.111.111.111
The ip address of Galileo chip is 222.222.222.222

Comment: Probably not the best idea ever to put your ip in the post... I have replace yours with a random one

Comment: Sorry wasnt thinking, thanks.

Comment: No problem! Good luck!

Comment: you can still see the IP in the edit history (let's not pretend), remove the post if you care.

Comment: What's the problem you're running in to?

Comment: When I run the javascript program it runs but I get a message saying "cannot POST"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the URL with a leading '/' in the Http In node

Comment: Hi, Ye that was the issue. Its working now. Thanks for the help.